# Rails nested fields when associating User to Roles model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some issues with the nested field here.  I've used nested fields in other views/controllers without issue.

I'm trying to associate a role to the user table from the roles table.

My role model looks like this:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

My user model has this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :role

...
```

The reason why it's set to optional is because current users don't yet have a role, and I need to apply it to those first (there are only two users in production at the moment so that's fine)

My user controller is like this for the permitted attributes and update

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
...
  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to admin_users_url, notice: 'User Account was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, roles_attributes: [:name])
  end

  def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

And the form to update the user roles:

```
.container.p-4
    %h1 Edit User Information

    = form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f|
        - if @user.errors.any?
            #error_explanation
            %h2
            = pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")
            prohibited this event from being saved:
            %ul
                - @user.errors.each do |error|
                    %li= error.full_message


        .row.mb-4
            .col
                = f.label :first_name, "First Name"
                = f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control border border-dark"
            .col
                = f.label :last_name, "Last Name"
                = f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control border border-dark"
        .form-group.mb-4
            = f.label :email, "Email Address"
            = f.email_field :email, class: "form-control border border-dark"

        %h2 User Role
        .form-group.mb-4
            = f.fields_for :roles do |f|
                = f.check_box :name, checked: false, value: "admin"
                = f.label :name, "Admin"
                
        .form-group.p-4.text-center
            = f.submit
```

When I hit update after checking "Admin", the terminal readout is that :roles is unpermitted.

I have a seperate Role controller that allows me to define the roles to associate users to.  the Roles table only has name:string and user:references.

So I'm not sure why it's not being permitted.

Comment: please share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.) you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want here is a join table to avoid denormalization:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
end

class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end
```

This will let you assign multiple users to a role without duplicating the string "admin" for example for each row and risking the denormalization and bugs that can occur if one row for example contains "Admin" instead. You would assign roles from an existing list to users with:

```
<% form_for([:admin, @user]) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :role_ids, 'Roles' %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, multiple: true) %>
  </div>

  # ...
<% end %>
```

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user)
        .permit(
          :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, 
          role_ids: []
        )
end
```

If you REALLY want to be able to create new roles on the fly while creating users you can use nested attributes. I would really just use AJAX instead through as it lets you handle the authorization logic in a seperate controller. You might want to consider that you might want to let some users assign roles but not invent new role definitions.

Comment: If you want a detailed explaination of the why check out the answers [to this question I asked on SE Software Engineering a while back](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/332260/database-design-for-a-role-based-access-system).

Comment: I set it up the way described above in your answer, yet still get this in the Terminal: "Unpermitted parameter: :role_ids".  I updated the list of roles to include Admin and Basic from the Roles model itself to see if multiple: true works but that doesn't.  it only lets me select one role.  when I hit update on he user form I get the unpermitted error even though I have it set up the way you describe above.

Comment: What does the incoming parameters hash look like? I'm not sure quite what to make of the error. `role_ids: []` will permit an array of permitted scalar values (in this case ids as strings) passed as `user[:user_ids]`. Are you maybe calling `f.collection` select on the scoped form builder that `fields_for` yields?

Comment: Processing by Admin::UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Patrick", "last_name"=>"Vellia", "email"=>"REDACTED", "role_ids"=>"35db991e-c1c0-4bc3-a49c-d6c189857d8e"}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"6fa69dc9-74ee-4d85-8038-0617f83d597b"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "41f0d4cc-5ef0-4994-8a5f-3786faf33eec"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Comment: User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "6fa69dc9-74ee-4d85-8038-0617f83d597b"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:46:in `set_user'
Unpermitted parameter: :role_ids

Comment: The above is what I get when I hit Update after setting the Role to "Basic"

Comment: Try `<%= form.collection_select(:role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true }) %>` its one of those annoying old methods in Rails with a wonky signature that takes multiple options hashes. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: Worked!  Was able to confirm the role took by displaying it in the view on the user grid.  But when I go back to the edit form, the "basic" isn't actually selected to show that item is currently applied.

Answer (score 0):

sticking with role ids and using bootstrap selectpicker the following worked as well and even preselects already set role

```rb
 = f.select :role_ids, options_for_select(Role.all.map{|role| [role.name, role.id]}, @user.role_ids), {},  {:multiple => true, inlcude_blank: false, class: "form-control input-sm selectpicker"}
```

and controller:

```rb
module Backend
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: %i[edit update]
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def edit
      @user.roles.build unless @user.roles.any?
    end

    def update
      if @user.update user_params
        redirect_to backend_users_path(@user), notice: 'Rollen erfolgreich aktualisiert'
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end

    private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, role_ids: [])
    end
  end
end
```